# how to comment ucf file in Doxygen

Tags: document, doxygen, vhdl

I want to use Doxygen to document a VHDL project. This works as expected for the VHDL source files. However, I'd like to add the ucf (user constraints file; Xilinx) too. The VHDL comment indicator "--!" obviously doesn't work. What comment indicator can be used for UCF files?

```
# file constr.ucf
# brief my pinout...
net "sig1"  LOC = "P1"; # my signal 1
net "sig2"  LOC = "P2"; # my signal 2 
net "sig3"  LOC = "P3";  # my signal 3
```

I see in doxygen log, that the file has been "reading" and "parsing". when I try to open "constraints" in HTML output, it reports "file not found".
when I use the EXTRACT_ALL function, the file is generated. However, the comments are not recognized as such!

here's the configuration file I use:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "My Project"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = D:/projekte/doxyTest
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = ucf=vhdl
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
SYMBOL_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = D:/projekte/doxyTest
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.d \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.idl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.cs \
                         *.php \
                         *.php3 \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.v
RECURSIVE              = NO
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       = 
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     = 
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_LINKS              = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_SCHEMA             = 
XML_DTD                = 
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = 
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration::additions related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = NO
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = 
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` is the comment idicator in UCF files.

From the [Xilinx Constraints Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_1/cgd.pdf) (page 32):

> To add comments to the UCF and NCF files, begin each comment line with
>   a pound (#) sign, as in the following example.

```
# file TEST.UCF
# net constraints for TEST design
NET "$SIG_0 MAXDELAY" = 10;
NET "$SIG_1 MAXDELAY" = 12 ns;
```

In your Doxygen configuration file, make sure you have the following option set:

```
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = YES
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = ucf=vhdl
```

And add `*.ucf` to `FILE_PATTERNS`.

In your HTML, you should now have a tab called Constraints under Design Unit List that shows the documentation for your UCF.

[image]

Comment: the question is, what comment indicator can be used for UCF files in order to let DOXYGEN recognize it as a comment!

Comment: @user2099419 Ah. I misunderstood. I've added the relevant information.

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work. here's how it looks:# file constr.ucf
# brief my pinout...
net "sig1"  LOC = "P1"; # my signal 1
net "sig2"  LOC = "P2"; # my signal 2 
net "sig3"  LOC = "P3";  # my signal 3

Comment: @baldyHDL I can't see anything in your comment after the :. Can you update your question?

Comment: @baldyHDL My mistake. I was trying to answer from memory. I just created a test case with UCF you gave in your updated question. You need `ucf=vhdl`, not `ucf=Tcl`.

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work for me... I added my configuration to the initial question.

Comment: @baldyHDL I created a project with the UCF from your question, a dummy VHDL file, and your Doxygen configuration file. The only thing I changed was the paths. I was able to reproduce your original problem of "file not found". When I enabled EXTRACT_ALL, I produced the output shown in my answer. What do you mean by " the comments are not recognized as such"? Can you post a screenshot of your output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```
#! file TEST.UCF
#! net constraints for TEST design
NET "$SIG_0 MAXDELAY" = 10;
NET "$SIG_1 MAXDELAY" = 12 ns;
```